# Swift switch statement on a tuple of optional booleans

Tags: switch-statement, swift, tuples, option-type

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use optionals inside a tuple inside a switch. The below .Some(let ...) ... syntax works as non-tuple, but inside a tuple I get expected separator stuff :(

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,Bool>()
dict["a"] = true

switch (dict["a"],dict["b") {
case (.Some(let a) where !a, .Some(let b) where b):
  println("false/nil, true")
case (.Some(let a) where a, .Some(let b) where !b):
  println("true, false/nil")
```

I want to avoid doing the following

```
    if let a = self.beaconList["a"] {
        if let b = self.beaconList["b"] {
            // a, b
        } else {
            // a, !b
        }
    } else {
        if let b = self.beaconList["b"] {
            // !a, b
        } else {
            // !a, !b
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, but to fix the syntax of what you are trying to do literally, you need to explicitly unbox the Optional, either by matching against .Some(false), or unwrapping it with ! (which I think is kind of weird, as you'll see)

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,Bool>()
dict["a"] = true
dict["c"] = false

func matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(a: Bool?, b: Bool?) -> String {
    switch (a, b) {
    case (.Some(true), let b) where b == .None || !b!: // gross
        return "a was true, but b was None or false"
    case (let a, .Some(true)) where a == .None || a == .Some(false):
        return "a was None or false and b was true"
    default:
        return "They both had a value, or they were both missing a value"
    }
}

matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(true, .None) // "a was true, but b was None or false"
matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(true, false) // "a was true, but b was None or false"
matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(.None, true) // "a was None or false and b was true"
matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(false, true) // "a was None or false and b was true"

matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(false, false) // "They both had a value, or they were both missing a value"
matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(true, true) // "They both had a value, or they were both missing a value"
matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(.None, .None) // "They both had a value, or they were both missing a value"
```

You could also try the following:

```
func noneToFalse(bool: Bool?) -> Bool {
    if let b = bool {
        return b
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func matchOneOrTheOther(a: Bool, b: Bool) -> String {
    switch (a, b) {
    case (true, false):
        return "a is true, b was false or None"
    case (false, true):
        return "a was false/None, b was true"
    default:
        return "both were true, or both were false/None"
    }
}

matchOneOrTheOther(noneToFalse(dict["a"]), noneToFalse(dict["b"]))
```

Here's a gist of the Playground I used while writing this answer: https://gist.github.com/bgrace/b8928792760159ca58a1

Comment: You can avoid the `!b!` grossness by making both the `a` & `b` args implicitly-unwrapped optionals with **`matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(a: Bool!, b: Bool!)`**.  Then your case `where`s become just **`where b == .none || !b:`** & **`where a == .none || !a:`**.  This is totally safe to do here because you're explicitly checking both `a` & `b` for `.none` before using the wrapped boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify!

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,String>()

dict["a"] = "the letter a"

switch (dict["a"],dict["b"]) {
  case (.None, let b):
    println("false/nil, true \(b)")
  case (let a, .None):
    println("true, false/nil \(a)")
  default:
    println("don't know") 
}
```

Comment: OP here: I want to match on nil/false (which .None does, I think), or true. Unfortunately "let a" or "let b" also allows nil/false :(, so I need to find a different way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is out of date. So I rewrote it in Swift 5.

```
    var dict = Dictionary<String,Bool>()
    dict["a"] = true
    dict["c"] = false

    func matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(_ a: Bool?, _ b: Bool?) -> String {
        switch (a, b) {
        case (.some(true), .none), (.some(true), .some(false)):
            return "a was true, but b was None or false"
        case (.none, .some(true)), (.some(false), .some(true)):
            return "a was None or false and b was true"
        default:
            return "They both had a value, or they were both missing a value"
        }
    }

    let xs: [Bool?] = [true, false, .none]
    for a in xs {
        for b in xs {
            print("a = \(String(describing: a)), b=\(String(describing: b))")
            print(matchOneOrTheOtherWithOptionals(a,b))
        }
    }
```